# linking with `cc` failed: exit code

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, rust-cargo

I am trying to build my docker file as shown in below using rust project, I am facing error.

> error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
> note: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=rust:1.52.1-alpine3.13
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS builder

ARG PROFILE=release
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apk add protoc
RUN cargo build --$PROFILE
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["app"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also add `musl-dev`to your `apk add` command.